# Problemas com template de função em c++ (Referência não definida para os métodos da classe)

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, compilação, template

Olá! 
Eu estou tentando compilar o seguinte código:

```
main:
```

````
#include "lista.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    no<int> *n; 
    n = new no<int>(4);
    n->setProx(new no<int>(5));
    cout << n->obterValor() << endl;
    return 0;
}```
````

lista.h

```
#ifndef lista_h
#define lista_h

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename type> class no{
private:
    type v;
    no *prox;
public:
    no(type v);
    void setProx(no* prox);
    type obterValor();
    no<type>* obterProx();
};

#endif
```

lista.cpp

```
#include "lista.h"
template<typename type>
no<type>::no(type v){
    this->v = v;
    this->prox = NULL;
}

template<typename type>
void no<type>::setProx(no<type>* prox){
    this->prox = prox;
}

template<typename type>
type no<type>::obterValor(){
    return this->v;
}

template<typename type>
no<type>* no<type>::obterProx(){
    return this->prox;
}
```

Quando eu compilo, conforme está no makefile:

```
all:    lista.o main.o
    g++ -o exe lista.o main.o
lista.o:    lista.cpp   lista.h
    g++ -c lista.cpp
main.o: main.cpp    lista.h
    g++ -c main.cpp
go:
    ./exe
clean:
    rm *.o && rm exe
```

E aí o terminal me retorna isso:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -o exe lista.o main.o
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: na função "main":
main.cpp:(.text+0x25): referência não definida para "no<int>::no(int)"
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x44): referência não definida para "no<int>::no(int)"
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x54): referência não definida para "no<int>::setProx(no<int>*)"
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x60): referência não definida para "no<int>::obterValor()"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:2: all] Error 1
```

Não entendi o porquê destas referências indefinidas para as funções. Os arquivos main.cpp e lista.cpp são compilados e geram o objeto '.o', mas o erro está na hora de criar o executável.

Answer (score 0):

O erro de referências não definidas é um erro do linker e quer dizer que o compilador sabe que a função foi declarada mas não sabe onde está a implementação. Isso aconteceu com o seu código pq um template não é um tipo definido e sim um molde para definir tipos no futuro. Toda vez que um tipo de template novo é declarado, o compilador busca pelo template para instanciar o novo tipo. Por isso que, por exemplo, no<int> é um tipo diferente de no<float>.

Quando vc compilou lista.o, o compilador não sabia da existência do tipo no<int> (declarado em main.cpp) e por isso não compilou a implementação para no<int>. Aí quando vc compilou main.o, o compilador tentou criar o tipo no<int> e encontrou a declaração do template no cabeçalho lista.h, mas não encontrou a definição dos métodos que estão em lista.cpp.

A solução é colocar a definição dos métodos de no no mesmo cabeçalho lista.h:

```
#ifndef lista_h                                                                                                         #define lista_h

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename type> class no{
private:
    type v;
    no *prox;
public:
    no(type v);
    void setProx(no* prox);
    type obterValor();
    no<type>* obterProx();
};

template<typename type>
no<type>::no(type v){
    this->v = v;
    this->prox = NULL;
}

template<typename type>
void no<type>::setProx(no<type>* prox){
    this->prox = prox;
}

template<typename type>
type no<type>::obterValor(){
    return this->v;
}

template<typename type>
no<type>* no<type>::obterProx(){
    return this->prox;
}

#endif
```

Eu sei que é estranho, mas esse é o padrão para definir templates em cabeçalhos.

Compilar lista.o é desnecessário, então sugiro que vc mude o seu makefile também:

```
all:
        g++ main.cpp -o exe

go:
        ./exe

clean:
        rm *.o && rm exe
```